Graph API throws error - "cannot be used like a method"
I have a code that was used from: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureProvisioningUsingFunctions/tree/main
  var getAllMessages = await graphClient.Users[UserPrincipalName].Chats
 .GetAllMessages()
 .GetAsync();

It shows a compiler error:

Non-invocable member 'ChatsRequestBuilder.GetAllMessages' cannot be used like a method.   AzureProvisioning   C:\Deeku\Personal\work\usermanagement\Code\AzureProvisioning.cs 728 Active


In addition to this, I have a code that is also not working:
  var signIns = await graphClient
    .AuditLogs
    .SignIns.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
       { 
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "UserPrincipalName eq '{UserPrincipalName}'  and isInteractive eq true and status/errorCode eq 0"; 
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "createdDateTime" 
   }; 
 });
 var signInsD = signIns.Distinct();

The error:

'SignInCollectionResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no accessible extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'SignInCollectionResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  AzureProvisioning


Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request

Yes, it works ,  now I left with  var signInsD = signIns.Distinct();  issue only

The error is because you are trying to use the Distinct method on the SignInCollectionResponse object. The Distinct method is not available directly on this type because it is not a collection type but a response object that contains a collection.

To getAllMessages, modify the code like below:
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Chats.GetAllMessages.GetAsGetAllMessagesGetResponseAsync((requestConfiguration) => { requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 2; });

Refer this MsDoc
The error is because you are trying to use the Distinct method on the SignInCollectionResponse object.

The Distinct method is not available directly on this type because it is not a collection type but a response object that contains a collection.

Hence as a workaround modify the code like below:
namespace GraphApiExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientSecret = "Secret";

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

            var userPrincipalName = "rukuser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";

            var result = await graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"UserPrincipalName eq '{userPrincipalName}' and isInteractive eq true and status/errorCode eq 0";
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "createdDateTime" };
            });

            if (result?.Value != null)
            {
                
                var signInsList = result.Value.ToList();

                // Apply Distinct based on some criteria, for example, by Id
                var distinctSignIns = signInsList
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Id)  // Group by Id
                    .Select(g => g.First())  // Select the first entry from each group
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var signIn in distinctSignIns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sign-in ID: {signIn.Id}, UPN: {signIn.UserPrincipalName}, Date: {signIn.CreatedDateTime}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No sign-ins found.");
            }
        }
    }
}


Reference: List signIns - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
